# How to say 热闹 in English

Tags: translation

How does one say 热闹i in English? I did some google search and the possible candidates are  lively, busy, and noisy. The connotation of 热闹  is crowdness, happy, noise, and excitment. Busy street in my opinion lacks the element of excitment. Is it? Also, busy club should be improper to describe the scenario. Somehow I feel coldness about busy street where people wear suits and walk quickly to work with apathy.

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it's about English. Anyway this one may fit: **Boisterous** adj. (of a person, event, or behavior) noisy, energetic, and cheerful; rowdy.

Comment: Boisterous is good.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is largely concerned with English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would venture "bustling". The already suggested "vibrant" captures the positive connotation of 热闹 nicely, but it does not carry the same sense of crowdedness and (as a result) exertion.

Answer (score 2):

Vibrant, as in:

> adj. Pulsing or throbbing with energy or activity: the vibrant streets of a big city.

https://www.wordnik.com/words/vibrant

In urban planning, the idea of having vibrant streets, neighborhoods, communities can often be seen as a goal to work towards:

> Vibrant Markets & Streets

http://www.inclusivecities.org/policy-planning/vibrant-markets-streets/

If you are in the market for associative housing such as Condo developments, look at the area amenities section in the sales brochure. You may notice the use of `vibrant` to describe the street, neighborhood or the community development in order to make you feel attracted to buy there.